# Grails JR report render as HTML

Tags: grails, jasper-reports, jasper-plugin

I am using the *JasperReports* plugin to generate a complex report. It is working fine with *pdf* file but requirement is that before download the pdf show exact pdf report preview   in html format.

I am just trying to use `"inline=true" "_format=html"`. 
When It rendering the html there are a big different in PDF and HTML.

The report in *html* format looks like this:

[image]

and in *pdf* format:

[image]

Can you please suggest how I can show exact *pdf* version in *html*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following line in your controller:

```
params.IS_USING_IMAGES_TO_ALIGN = false
```